# Проблемы загрузчика. Linux и Windows на разных дисках

Tags: linux, windows, unix, windows-8, dual-boot

Столкнулся с надобностью установить `linux` на машину, где уже установлена `windows 8`, но так, чтобы системы находились на разных дисках.

Есть диск `C:/` на нем стоит Windows и `D:/` на который предполагается поставить linux.

Ставил `ubuntu 14.04`, поставил в uefi режиме, выполнил boot-repair, но grub также не грузится в режиме `uefi+legacy`. Просто в режиме `uefi` имеем строку shell'а.

Менял порядок загрузки дисков, не помогло - грузится windows без возможности выбора другой ОС, отличной от windows.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ поставить linux на другой диск, при этом создав возможность выбора ОС при включении машины?

Comment: При установке показывает строку типа: " на данном пк обнаружены другие ОС.....  Установить загрузчик для корректной работы?" не дословно но все же где то так, если соглашаетесь то будет видно и Ubuntu и windows

Comment: Просто тут дело в том, что вызывается не grub, а загрузчик windows, который не хочет видеть ничего, кроме "окон".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решил таким образом. Скачал утилиту easyBCD, перед этим установил ubuntu на другой диск. После установки запустил утилиту, с помощью нее создал запись для linux с указанием жесткого диска на котором располагается сама ОС.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только вместо GRUB (Legacy) указал GRUB 2. Перезагрузил машину, после чего выдался список с двумя ОС, среди которых был linux. После выбора linux открывается grub, а уже из него, нужная ОС запускается без проблем.